# How to add my JavaScript files to a Rails app?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple Rails scaffolded application, and would like to add a bunch of JavaScript files (including a special version of JQuery) to support new client-side features.

I added the *.js files to `public/javascripts` and added `<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>` at the top of the `new.html.erb` where they are needed.

PROBLEM: When I first call `$(document).ready(function(){` in this ERB, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`, which seems to mean that my JQuery library has in fact not been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to be loading your javascript in the `<head>` section of your HTML instead, to make sure it gets loaded at the proper time. When you put it in your `new.html.erb` file, it's getting loaded in the body instead.

Find you layout, by default `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, and put it in there in the `<head>` section instead. This will then be applied to your `new.html.erb` page.

Comment: That solved the problem immediately! I suspect the order in which the javascripts are imported is important, and can't be controlled with :all

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `jquery-rails` gem by any chance ? Check [this](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) out.

Comment: My Gemfile and Gemfile.lock do not contain jquery.

Comment: Maybe you could try installing that instead? Anything I would try is to have "alert('something')" in the document ready. I have also encountered an error like yours, but still managed to display the alert message (or whatever is supposed to run in the jQuery function).

Comment: If I bring my own (customized) JQuery then I shouldn't need Rails' JQuery, right? I am also worried it might break mine...